# Two marquees in same page with different styles

Tags: jquery, html, css, marquee

i want to have two marquee style in my one page.

One scrolling right to left and the other one scrolling bottom to top.

But in my case both are scrolling in same direction and they both in same sync which i dont want . below is my code

```
<table>

<tr>
<td class="msg" align="left" width="170">Application Availability : </td>
<td>
<div class="marquee">first data to scroll right to left</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

```
<tr>
<td>
<div class="marquee" style="background:#6699ff; width:840px;">text to scroll bottom to top</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>

<tr>
<td>
<div class="marquee" style="background:#ffcc66;width:840px;">text to scroll bottom to top</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
```

my java script is as below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var $diaplay = $('#display'), counter = 0;
$('.marquee')
    .bind('beforeStarting', function(){

    })
    .bind('finished', function(){
        counter++;

    })

.marquee({
    duration: 10000
})
});
```

If i am trying to use the below scripts, both are moving up in small height

```
 $(function () {
$('.marquee').marquee({
    speed: 10000,
    gap: 50,
    delayBeforeStart: 0,
    direction: 'up'
    //,duplicated: true
});
});
```

Comment: give each element an ID and initialize them separately